# Getting error trying to create an app using create-react-app : npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-install, create-react-app

I am just starting to create my first react app using create-react-app package.But getting this error!

I have tried it with :

```
npx create-react-app my-friends
&&
npm install -g create-react-app(succesful)
create-react-app my-friends(error)
```

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '...oader":"~0.5.0","vm-b'

Comment: I suppose the JSON of package.json is invalid, is that correct? It should be mentioned in the error. If so; can you provide the JSON in package.json?

Comment: How can I check ,whether my JSON of package.json is valid or not?

Comment: You can use JSONLint for example, to see if the JSON is valid: https://jsonlint.com/.  Can you provide the contents of package.json to your post, so I can take a look also?

Comment: I checked the contents of package.json using jsonlint.com 
and it says its valid !

Comment: sorry the file is too large to provide here (about 1300 chars)(limit is about 600)

Comment: Any other option for sharing?

Comment: can there be any problem of location of these files?Its in the 
C:\Users\vidit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

Comment: You can check it out here :- https://github.com/Arushacked/createreatapp

Comment: Could you please provide some more information about the versions you're using of npx, npm & create-react-app (with `--version`). Executing all the commands one after another works for me (using `create-react-app my-friends` instead of the last command). Also the package.json in your Git repo seems to be fine and working.

Comment: npx -v>
6.4.1

npm -v>
6.4.1
create-react-app -V >
3.0.1

Comment: According to the Github readme (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), running one of the commands (`npx create-react-app my-friends` or `npm init react-app my-app`) should be enough to init a new react project.  npx already comes with npm 5.2+, so you wouldn't have to `npm install -g create-react-app`, since you have version 6.4.1 of npm.

Comment: I uninstalled the create-react-app and used (npx create-react-app my-friends) command .....AND IT WORKED ..........Thanks for your guidance